# Vue router authentication-guard unable to recognize my vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, auth-guard

I am trying to guard a vue component in the global router.js file using the `beforeEnter()`, however i keep getting a type error in the console thats says

> cannot read property getters of undefined

Here is an example of router.js file

```js
import login from './views/login'
//the component I want to guard
import admin from './views/adminPage'
//my Vuex store
import { store } from './store'


Vue.use(Router)


export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: login
    },
    {
      path: '/admin'
      name: 'admin',
      component: admin,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next){
        if(!store.getters.currentUser){
          next('/login')
        } else {
          next()
        }
      }
      
    }
  ]
})
```

```js
//this is an example of my store.js file

export default new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        currentUser: null
      },
      //....
      
      getters: {
        currentUser: state => state.currentUser
      }
    })

<
```

Note: I believe the issue is here in the router.js file because I call my vuex getters all across the app files without problems.

Comment: Can you post your `store` code?

Comment: done, PS, the function that sets the user is called in the created life hook in my `app.vue` component

Comment: First try `import store from './store'`, not `import { store } from './store'`.

Comment: that worked indeed, now i am a little confused on when and when not to use the `{}` import method. but thanks very much anyway :)